# To make html elements closer to each other

Tags: html, css, google-sheets, materialize

I have this long form for users with several html elements.
I used [Materialize](https://materializecss.com/text-inputs.html) framework for it.
Here's the collpsible [link](https://materializecss.com/collapsible.html).

The form is getting too long.

**How to remove some space between elements and make it all narrower so I don't need to scroll down?**

I didn't find it in framework options.

Here's the html code for the elements:

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <i class="material-icons prefix">add</i>
      <input id="stat" type="text" class="validate">
      <label for="stat">Добавить новую статистику</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <i class="material-icons prefix">assignment</i>
      <input id="des" type="text" class="validate">
      <label for="des">Добавить описание статистики</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s1">
      <i class="material-icons prefix">trending_down</i>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s8">
      <h6>
        Добавить минимальное значение
      </h6>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s3">
      <input id="des" type="text" class="validate">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s1">
      <i class="material-icons prefix">trending_up</i>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s8">
      <h6>
        Добавить максимальное значение
      </h6>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s3">
      <input id="des" type="text" class="validate">
    </div>
  </div>

  <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small #039be5 light-blue darken-1" id="btn"><i class="material-icons right">send</i>Добавить</a>
  <p> </p>
  <ul class="collapsible">
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>Добавить данные в статистики:</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body">
        <span>
      
   <div class="row">   
   <div class="input-field col s1">
   <p>
  <i class="material-icons prefix">wb_sunny</i>
  </p>
   </div>   
   <div class="input-field col s7">  
  <select class="icons browser-default" id="weeksSel2" onChange ="getWeekText2();">  
  <option value="" disabled selected>Выберите неделю</option>
  </select>
  </div> 
  </div>          
      
    </span>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
<!-- end of container -->
```

[image]

Comment: I recommend reducing/removing padding and margins with in line style. If your inline styles are being overwritten then try adding !important to your styles so they don't get over written.

Comment: That's margin and padding issue. Before you using "!important" ensure that your overriding styles are included after the framework styles... you would not need !important as css works with _last in, first out_

Comment: Guys, thanks. How to override framework styles, what you usually do for that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very much hands on the materializecss, but I found the same problem somebody is facing, have a look this might can help you out.

As per below link you need to consolidate all the `col` element in the single `row`.

[Spacing Between Rows with Materialize CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30156593/spacing-between-rows-with-materialize-css)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to remove `margin-bottom` from `.row`.

```
<div class="row">
```

Add another class to your div with class `row`, say `custom-row`

```
<div class="row custom-row">
```

and add style:

```
.custom-row {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important; /*this will override margin-bottom:10px from '.row'
}
```

This will keep all the styles from `.row` but override the `margin-bottom`

Hope it helps!